# Efficiently preview thousands of svg icons?

Tags: svg, software-recommendation, batch-processing

I stumbled on the [Papirus](https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme/) icon theme (GPL licenced). One can download the package with thousands of svg-files. Opening every file in Inksacpe or Firefox is not a practical approach to get an overview over all icons. I would like to see 50 icons at once, along with their filename. Is there a free software for that purpose or a {bash, python, ...}-snippet which renders N svg files side by side on a png?

Comment: This kind of collection of thumbnail images is often referred to as a ‘contact sheet’. There are various free online resources for creating contact sheets - I’m sure you’ll find one that accepts SVGs as input.

Comment: I run a local host.... it's a simple PHP script loop to show all images in a directory. Could be done fairy easily via MAMP or LAMP if you have that running.

Comment: Look what ImageMagick can do for you.

Comment: A reasonably capable file manager might do this already. What platform are you on?

Comment: I am on Debian GNU Linunx with KDE. I meanwhile solved the problem with a python script which generates a html-file including the pictures. I plan to clean that up and share it here and on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by the comment of Scott, I decided to write my own solution: A python script which generates a static html file including all images, see https://github.com/cknoll/imagedirpreview.

Even with >3000 svg-symbols it is considerably fast, see video:

[image: Video (hosted at VIMEO)]

Comment: Very similar to what I have PHP doing. I just went without any templates since mine is really for in house only. I've tried a ton of image "catalogers" and they all were nowhere near as fast. And the great thing.. just point to a different directory if you want to preview other image sets.

Comment: I solved my original problem rather quick as well. But then I thought, it would be nice to make that solution publicly available to let others solve that problem within one minute.

Comment: I downloaded it from github but don't have pip installed, nor do the ubuntu reps (16.04) offer pip. But I have a lot of python stuff installed. Can I build/install it without pip?

Comment: @userunknown installation without pip should be possible. Only requirement which is not in the standard library is `jinja2` (templating system). However I would strongly recommend using pip, and I would be really surprised if this was not available in ubuntu 16.04. I use debian an the package name is `python3-pip`. Also see: <https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/>. Nevertheless, feel free to open an issue on github.

Comment: Aha, so apt search jinja2 shows, beneath python2 and others, python3-jinja2. I would take that, right? And yes, with python(3)-pip I find pip too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An icon manager application would work for this purpose too. I guess these applications could also be called icon libraries. I don't Know if there are similar apps for Linux or Windows but there are a few for Mac.

They function about the same as to font managers.

I personally use [iconjar](https://geticonjar.com/) on mac. I use it to store other graphics too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Put many SVG-graphics on a HTML-page for preview
#   - depends on some command to get the screen resolution, here xdpyinfo
#   - usage: svg-overview.sh [N]
#     N: Number of pictures to put in row. Default is 6
#   - generates a html-file svg-preview.html where the images are 
#     referenced, so loading big svg files will put some load the CPU
#
PFILE="svg-preview.html"
# xdpyinfo is available on linux, probably not on MacOS etc. so you might need
# some other method to evaluate width and height.
dim=$(xdpyinfo | grep dimension | spalten 3)
# dim=1600x1200
w=${dim/x*/}
h=${dim/*x/}  # This comment only fools the code layouter */
perRow=${1:-6}
x=$((w/perRow))
y=$((h/perRow))
echo "Width of screen: $w height: $h per Row: $perRow x=$x y=$y"

head () {
  echo '<html><head><title>'
  pwd
  echo '</title></head><body><table>'
}

count=0

content () {
  for file in *.svg ; do
    if ((count%perRow == 0)) ; then
      echo "<tr><td><a href='$file'><img src='"$file"' alt='$file' width='"$x"' heigth='"$y"'/></a></td>"
    else
      if ((count%perRow != perRow-1)) ; then
        echo "<td><a href='$file'><img src='"$file"' alt='$file' width='"$x"' heigth='"$y"'/></a></td>"
      else
        echo "<td><a href='$file'><img src='"$file"' alt='$file' width='"$x"' heigth='"$y"'/></a></td></tr>"
      fi
    fi
    ((++count))
  done
}

tail () {
  #
  # trailing </tr>, if the number of pictures didn't fill the row
  #
  if (( count%perRow != 0 )) ; then
    echo "</tr>" >>$PFILE
  fi

  echo "</table></body></html>"
}

head > $PFILE
content >> $PFILE
tail >> $PFILE
```

The preview file is overwritten without notice.